# How to display a property of selection object while hovering cursor over combo box item in Vaadin

Tags: events, combobox, mousehover, vaadin23

In my Vaadin (v.23.2.6) application I am creating a bean of class Book. This bean has set of tags.
Tags are retrieved from the database and contain two properties - tagName and tagDescription.
In my UI form I specified MultiSelectComboBox for Tags.

```
this.tagsField = new MultiSelectComboBox<>("Tags");
this.tagsField.setAllowCustomValue(true);
this.tagsField.setAutoOpen(false);
this.tagsField.setItemLabelGenerator(Tag::getTagName);
```

It is working, but I do want to display value of ***tagDescription*** when cursor is hovering over the ***tagName*** in the selection list.
What kind of event listener I can use for that purpose? Shall I use **Notification** or there is something else that can help me with this implementation?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's technically possible, you don't want to listen to hover (mouseover) events on the server. That's overkill and will lead to a lot of unnecessary network traffic. Instead, you can take care of it in the client with a Renderer. For example, using the standard HTML `title` attribute:

```java
tagsField.setRenderer(LitRenderer.<Tag>of(
    "<span title='${item.description}'>${item.name}</span>")
        .withProperty("description", Tag::getTagDescription)
        .withProperty("name", Tag::getTagName)
);
```

Comment: I did add the code you recommended:
        this.tagsField.setRenderer(LitRenderer.<Tag>of("<span title='${item.description}'>${item.name}</span>")
        .withProperty("description", Tag::getTagDescription).withProperty("name", Tag::getTagName));
Now it is throwing NPE:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.LitRenderer.<init>(LitRenderer.java:80) ~[vaadin-renderer-flow-23.2.6.jar:na]
 at com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.LitRenderer.of(LitRenderer.java:128) ~[vaadin-renderer-flow-23.2.6.jar:na]

Comment: My bad. I did look inside the LitRenderer source code and figured out why it was throwing NPE. I placed the code in the constructor, where I was setting properties of all fields. No wonder that UI.getCurrent() there returns null. BTW, I do think it is a bug and line litRendererCount = UI.getCurrent().getElement()               .getProperty("__litRendererCount", 0); shall be rep[laced with 
litRendererCount = (UI.getCurrent() == null)? 0 : UI.getCurrent().getElement()
.getProperty("__litRendererCount", 0);
Meanwhile, I override method open() and moved code there. It is working now.

Comment: Can this solution used for something other than combo-box? I used it for assigning tags to books. Now I do need to display book info, including tags. I want to show them like here at SO (see above at the question).

Comment: You could use a VirtualList, which supports Renderers: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/virtual-list

Comment: I do not think VirtualList is applicable here. I am thinking of something like horizontal line of labels, displaying tagName and showing tagDescription when mouse hovering over it. There will be 2-3 tags (no more than 5 for sure).
BTW, will the bug in LitRenderer fixed in the nearest future?